How can I test in mocha/chai that my zip download was successfull?
I have a function where I create a zip file and I directly download it.
    const zip = ZipFile(buffers);
    
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      'Content-Length': zip.length,
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=timesheets.zip'
    });
    res.write(zip);
    res.end();

all works but how can I say in mocha/chai that my file download was success ? I dont want to download the file I only want to know how can I test it that was success

I am unclear on what exactly you are trying to do. Both the status code and the file are part of the same response, so you can't check for the status code without "downloading" the file.
